# Trouble compiling VS2015 application with mono/xbuild

Tags: linux, mono, c#

I'm new to programming, but not new to Linux. I recently began a Programming class in C# and we're using Visual Studio 2015 to write applications and therefore MSbuild to compile them. However, at home I'd like to compile everything with mono, but when I try I get several errors and it refuses to compile. 
This is the program I run:

```
$ xbuild Dice_Game.sln
```

and this is stderr:

```
Errors:

/home/dj/programs/c#_programs/Dice_Game/Dice_Game.sln (default targets)  ->
(Build target) ->
/home/dj/programs/c#_programs/Dice_Game/Dice_Game.csproj (default     targets) ->
/usr/local/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets     (CoreCompile target) ->

CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Object' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.ValueType' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Attribute' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Int32' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UInt32' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Int64' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UInt64' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Single' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Double' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Char' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Int16' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Decimal' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.SByte' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Byte' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UInt16' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.String' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Enum' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Delegate' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.MulticastDelegate' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Void' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Array' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Type' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Collections.IEnumerator' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Collections.IEnumerable' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.IDisposable' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.IntPtr' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UIntPtr' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.RuntimeFieldHandle' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.RuntimeTypeHandle' is not defined or imported
CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Exception' is not defined or imported

 4 Warning(s)
 31 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.2374970
```

It seems like I can make this work... I'm just not experienced enough with Mono to make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please change your project's target framework to .NET 4.5.

Currently Mono does not support .NET 4.5.1 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Pulled half of my hair on this. There are many ways to install Mono, and some will install an outdated version. I remember following some instructions for VS Code and Omnisharp.

So, to get an up to date installation, follow the instructions on the [download page of mono](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin) to set up the apt source, then do:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall mono-complete
sudo apt upgrade
```

`xbuild` started working but said it was deprecated so use `msbuild`.

Comment: Six years later on Fedora and pulling the other half.

Comment: Ended up forcing a target framework with `xbuild /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.0"`

Answer (score 0):

on my Ubuntu Bionic setup this was fixed by installing the `mono-reference-assemblies-*` packages.
(for some reason they are not installed with `mono-devel`)